# how to unmock a single instance method with jest

Tags: ecmascript-6, mocking, jestjs, es6-class

coming from rspec, i am having trouble understanding mocking with jest. the approach i am trying for, is to automock a class's constructor and all of it's functions, and then unmock them one by one to test only that one function. the only documentation i can find on it, is with using 2 classes, mocking 1 class, and then testing that those functions are called from the other unmocked class.

below is a basic, contrived idea of what i am trying to do. can someone direct me to the jest-way of doing this?

foo.js

```
class Foo
  constructor: ->
    this.bar()
    this.baz()
  bar: ->
    return 'bar'
  baz: ->
    return 'baz'
```

foo_test.js

```
// require the class
Foo = require('foo')

// mock entire Foo class methods
jest.mock('foo')

// unmock just the bar method
jest.unmock(Foo::bar)

// or by
Foo::bar.mockRestore()

// and should now be able to call
foo = new Foo
foo.bar() // 'bar'
foo.baz() // undefined (still mocked)

// i even tried unmocking the instance
foo = new Foo
jest.unmock(foo.bar)
foo.bar.mockRestore()
```

Answer (score 18):

[`mockFn.mockRestore()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockrestore) worked for me with `jest@24.9.0`:

```
// Create a spy with a mock
const consoleInfoSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'info').mockImplementation(() => {})

// Run test or whatever code which uses console.info
console.info('This bypasses the real console.info')

// Restore original console.info
consoleInfoSpy.mockRestore()
```

Answer (score 11):

This does not strictly apply to the OP, but answer-seekers may end up here.  You can mock a module except certain parts for *all tests* like so.

****mocks**/saladMaker.js**

```js
// Let Jest create the mock.
const saladMaker = jest.genMockFromModule('../saladMaker');

// Get the unmocked chop method.
const {chop} = jest.requireActual('../saladMaker');

// Patch it in.
saladMaker.chop = chop;

module.exports = saladMaker;
```

The key part is to use `requireActual` to get at the unmocked module.

[bypassing module mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/bypassing-module-mocks)

Comment: jest.genMockFromModule() is deprecated so we can use jest.createMockFromModule()

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to get the original module after mocking it in Jest. What `jest.mock` does is to replace the module with your mock.

So even you write:

```
Foo = require('foo')
jest.mock('foo')
```

Jest will hoist the `jest.mock('foo')` call on top of the call stack, so it's the first thing that happens when the test starts. This will also affect all other modules you import and that import `foo.js`.

You could try to use [`spyOn`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) to spy on functions of an object, should work with classes as well, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: yea i have been playing with that too, but having the same issue. i was also looking at try to just mock the constructor, but can't seem to figure that out either. somehow jest is doing it, but looking through their source code may take longer than just figuring it out myself

Answer (score 1):

I have tried a lot of things, but what eventually worked for me is (using Create React App):

setupTests.ts

```js
jest.mock("./services/translations/translationsService", () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: {
    initDict: (): void => undefined,
    translate: (key: Phrases): string => key,
  },
  t: (key: Phrases): string => key,
}));
```

Which mocks the module for all tests. In order to unmock for a single test suite, I did:

```js
jest.mock("../../../services/translations/translationsService", () =>
  jest.requireActual("../../../services/translations/translationsService")
);

describe(() => { /* test suite goes here and uses real implementation */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Jest@27.4.7**

```
const mockChildComponent = jest.mock('../../../src/components/common/childComponent', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: (props: Prop) => (
    <div data-test-id="stub-chart-panel">
      {props.label}
    </div>
  ),
}));

test('mock child', async () => {
  const wrapper = mount(
      <ParentComponent />
  );
  expect(....);
});

mockChildComponent.restoreAllMocks();

test('default child component ', async () => {
  const wrapper = mount(
      <ParentComponent />
  );
  expect(....);
});
```